# Python/Xarray: How to convert time dtype from datetime64[ns] to integer (with appropriate units)?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, python-xarray

I am using a Xarray Dataset to contain data I'm feeding into a TensorFlow DNN, and when I call the `train()` function I eventually get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert value dtype('<M8[ns]') to a TensorFlow DType.
```

My assumption is that this is because of the dtype of the dataset's time dimension/coordinate variable is `datetime64[ns]` which maps to the `<M8[ns]` dtype:

```
In [1]: np.dtype('datetime64[ns]') == np.dtype('<M8[ns]')
Out[1]: True
```

I'd like to modify the Dataset so that the `time` dimension/coordinate variable instead has an integer type that will perhaps be more palatable to TensorFlow.

In the past, I've always used integer types for time variables along with units such as 'days since 2000-01-01 00:00:00'. In this case, if using an integer dtype the units would need to be in minutes or seconds since the time steps are in 30-minute increments.

Some info around my current time variable:

```
In [2]: ds['time'].coords['time']
Out[2]: <xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 720)>
        array(['2000-12-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-12-27T00:30:00.000000000',
               '2000-12-27T00:59:59.000000000', ..., '2001-01-10T22:30:00.000000000',
               '2001-01-10T23:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-10T23:29:59.000000000'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]')
        Coordinates:
          * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-12-27 2000-12-27T00:30:00 ...
        Attributes:
            long_name:  time
        bounds:     time_bnds

In [3]: ds['time'].encoding
Out[3]: {'calendar': 'noleap',
         'dtype': dtype('float64'),
         'original_shape': (720,),
         'source': '/content/fv091x180L26_dry_HS.cam.h0.2000-12-27-00000.nc',
         'units': 'days since 2000-12-27 00:00:00'}
```

Is there a function typically used for this sort of conversion, or do I just roll my own using timedeltas, etc.? Could I somehow request for xarray to convert the time variable into something more vanilla when reading from NetCDF? `xarray.open_dataset()` with `decode_times=False`?

Comment: `(ds['time'] - np.datetime64('2000-01-01 00:00:00)).astype(int) / (30 * 60 * 1e9)` is what you want?

Comment: Thanks @KeisukeFUJII ! `xarray.open_dataset()` with `decode_times=False` seems to have done the trick, i.e. my time values come out as floats now using that approach. These are digestible by TensorFlow, so issue solved for now.